# Am I not understanding ArrayList or am I missing something?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm trying to create a very, very simple program. 
I want my class called `Text` to simply print out a string, specifically, one letter.
Then in my second class called Window, I want to create an ArrayList of that class, iterate through the list and call the method of my Text class to print out the string. But it does not print anything.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Text {

    private String a;

    public void printA() {
        a = "a";
        System.out.print(a);
    }

}
```

and the other class..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Window {

    private ArrayList<Text> string = new ArrayList<Text>(5);

    public Window() {
        addText();
    }

    public void iterate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < string.size() - 1; i++) {
            string.get(i).printA();
        }
    }

    public void addText() {
        for (int i = 0; i <string.size() - 1; i++) {
            string.add(new Text());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window wind = new Window();
        wind.iterate();
    }

}
```

Comment: `new ArrayList<Text>(5)` doesn't do what you think it does; check the Javadocs...

Comment: class Window doesnt extend Text class - how do you want to call printA() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify iterate to:

```
public void iterate(){
    System.out.println(string.size()-1);
    for(int i = 0; i < string.size()-1;i++){
        string.get(i).printA();

    }
}
```

You will get -1

Let me explain why:

Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. `private ArrayList<Text>string = new ArrayList<Text>(5);` merely sets the capacity of the underlying array that is the data structure that implement the `ArrayList` object. size() returns the number of objects inside of the ArrayList not the capcity

```
public void addText(){
    for(int i = 0; i <string.size()-1;i++){
        string.add(new Text());

    }
}
```

The for loop's expression doesn't evaluate to true, and therefore you never add a single object to the loop which is why iterate would print -1 if you added the print statement there

Comment: Thank you for the great explenation. I have so many posts I want to choose as the answer but I can only pick one. I read all of them. So thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i <string.size()-1;i++){
    string.add(new Text());

}
```

initialy the arraylist is empty, so string.size() == 0
the forlus wil not be executed, change to

```
public void addText(){
     string.add(new Text())
}
```

or even better

```
public void addText(Text t){
     string.add(t)
}
```

that way you can add Text-object created with different constructors

Answer (score 0):

problem it this method.

```
public void addText(){
        for(int i = 0; i <string.size()-1;i++){
            string.add(new Text());

        }
    }
```

this doesn't add anything at all. because `string.size()` is 0.

may be you should change it to

```
public void addText(int size){
    for(int i = 0; i <size-1;i++){
        string.add(new Text());

    }
}
```

**Ps:** `new Arraylist<Text>(5)` actually creates an empty list with initial **capacity** = 5 (not size). See it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

The

```
new ArrayList<Text>(5);
```

Doesn't mean you have 5 elements array. It means that this is just initial capacity of internal array for storing elements. Due to this your init code:

```
public void addText(){
    for(int i = 0; i <string.size()-1;i++){
        string.add(new Text());

    }
}
```

faces no elements in the list with `string.size()` = 0.

Use this instead (If you like to add 5 elements):

```
public void addText(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++){
        string.add(new Text());

    }
}
```

There is no problem to add more elements (even if the initial capacity was only '5'). From docu "As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically."

Comment: Thank you very much :)

I'd upvote your post but i dont have the rep.

Answer (score 0):

Well for stater your method in Text needs parameter so it KNOWS to take in 'a' and if you're variable in your parameter is going to be 'a' as well you need use "this." so that the compiler knows that the two are different.

public class Text {

```
private String a;

public void printA(String a) {
    this.a = "a";
    System.out.print(a);
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

What you are doing wrong is that you are creating the `ArrayList` with a capacity of 5, but it does not yet have 5 objects in it. Thus, the `addText` method does nothing. Here's a version that works:

```
public void addText(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        string.add(new Text()); 
    }
}
```

Note that `string.size() - 1` has been changed to `4`, becuase `string.size()` is 0, and you want to add 4 elements to the list. Also, your `iterate` method could use a little refactoring:

```
public void iterate(){
    for(Text text : string){
        string.get(i).printA();
    }
}
```

Instead of a simple loop, an enhanced `for` is used instead. This is no more than a typing shortcut, but it improves efficiency for `LinkedList`s.

Comment: This doesn't compile and hence *doesn't* work. Also, you didn't answer the question *"What am I doing wrong?"*.